# How to pack a tab in a JTabbedPane to the size of the frame if tabs have different size components?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtabbedpane

How can I pack the frame to the size of a tab in a `JTabbedPane`, so on every click on a tab the size of a frame becomes the perfect fit?

I've tried to use frame.pack() in every tab but no result.

I expect to pack tab components to their perfect fit but it is taking the size of the first tab so the components are so widely separated from borders.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `pack` will pack around the available content.  `JTabbedPane` is calculating it's preferred size based on the largest width/height of all the tabs

Comment: how can i make it prefer the size of the actual components in the selected tab and not the largest of all tabs @MadProgrammer

Comment: I don’t think you can, as I said jtabbedpane is using all the tabs to determine a suitable size